# HBase Shell hangs / freezes

Tags: hbase, ubuntu-12.04, cloudera, freeze, hbase-shell

I've installed HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 in [Pseudo-Distributed mode](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/HBase+Installation#HBaseInstallation-ConfiguringHBaseinPseudodistributedMode).
*hbase-master*, *hbase-regionserver* and *zookeeper-server* are running on this machine; the HDFS is running on another machine (property *hbase.rootdir* set accordingly).
Now I have a problem with the "hbase shell": whenever I submit a create table statement like

```
   create 'tbl1', {NAME => 'd', COMPRESSION => 'GZ'}
```

the shell hangs (it does not return anything; waits forever) and I have to kill it with ctrl+c. However the command always gets executed and when I submit the "list" command in the "hbase shell", the table gets listed. Also the web-ui can be accessed through the default port 60010 and the created tables are listed under the user tables. I've already cleaned the hbase directory on the HDFS, cleaned the zookeeper logs, corrected the hosts file (changed 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1). What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check in your HBASE web UI. whether "Regions in Transition" is active for that particular table. If so then the problem may persist. Wait for the transition to complete else Restart the Hbase Master. If this problem comes offend kindly paste ur hbase logs here.

Answer (score 1):

After rebooting the server the issue has disappeared! Maybe it had something to do with the **leap second bug** (30 June / 1 July 2012). Some Java processes had a very high CPU load without any obvious reason.