# Hbase shell freezes after table creation

Tags: hbase, freeze

**I- Summary:**

I run into an issue while testing Hadoop (2.6.0)/Hbase (1.0.1.1) on a fully distributed mode. The problem is that everytime I create a Table, the query freezes, with the error "handler.CreateTableHandler : failed. null". Even though, when I check,  the table is successfully created.

**II- Set-up and configuration :**

I have a quit simple setup of 5 machines; one namenode/HMaster, one resourceManager/ZKQuorum, and three slaves, two of them are region servers, while the third is a backup HMaster.

**III- Porblem**

Hadoop is up and running, but HBase surprisingly freezes after I create a table. The behaviour remains the same either by doing it through HBase shell, or Java API. Despite the freezing part, the table is everytime created.

As you can notice at the **last log entry** below,  the createTableHandler fails with the msg null.

I looked around for posts similar to mine, I only found 2. Whereas the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505289/hbase-shell-hang-when-create-table) one has no answer, in the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395530/hbase-shell-hangs-freezes), a suggestion was to reboot the server.
Indeed, I tried this solution, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.
Other solutions I tried were:

1. Cleaning ZK
2. Hbase offlineMetaRepair
3. Assigning HMaster to different machines.

Does anybody have an idea where this could come from ?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
2015-07-08 20:43:36,645 INFO[B.defaultRpcServer.handler=3,queue=0,port=16020] master.HMaster: Client=hadoop//10.10.10.105 create '__10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1', {NAME => 'c', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME =>  'p', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 't', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}

2015-07-08 20:43:36,681 INFO [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-HDPNN:16020-0] handler.CreateTableHandler: Create table __10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1 

2015-07-08 20:43:36,716 INFO [RegionOpenAndInitThread->>__10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1-1] regionserver.HRegion: creating HRegion __10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1 HTD == '__10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1', {NAME => 'c', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'p', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 't', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'} RootDir = hdfs://10.10.10.105:9000/hbase/.tmp Table name == __10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1

2015-07-08 20:43:36,727 INFO [RegionOpenAndInitThread-__10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1-1] regionserver.HRegion: Closed __10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1,,1436388216644.65865aede9173944a90889efed79b0a7.

2015-07-08 20:43:36,731 INFO [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-HDPNN:16020-0] hbase.MetaTableAccessor: Added 1
2015-07-08 20:43:36,739 WARN [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-HDPNN:16020-0] zookeeper.ZKTableStateManager: Moving table __10.10.10.113_Class_model0_gen0_1 state from ENABLING to ENABLED
2015-07-08 20:43:36,742 INFO [MASTER_TABLE_OPERATIONS-HDPNN:16020-0] handler.CreateTableHandler: failed. null
```